# Can a Java program detect that it's running low on heap space?

Tags: java, memory

I will be running a genetic algorithm on my roommate's computer for the whole weekend, and I'm afraid that it could run out of memory over such a long run. However, my algorithm works in such a way that would make it reasonably easy to trim less useful results, so if there was a way to tell when my program is about to run out of heap space, I could probably make room and keep going for some more time.

Is there a way to be notified when the JVM is running out of heap space, before the OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically monitor Java heap size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163228/how-to-dynamically-monitor-java-heap-size)

Comment: @Andreas_D, this question treats about monitoring the program externally. I want my own program to react when it's about to run out of heap space.

Comment: the answers to the other question include internal and external monitoring solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can register a javax.management.NotificationListener that is called when a certain threshold is hit.

Something like

```
final MemoryMXBean memBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
final NotificationEmitter ne = (NotificationEmitter) memBean;

ne.addNotificationListener(listener, null, null);

final List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memPools = ManagementFactory
    .getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
for (final MemoryPoolMXBean mp : memPools) {
  if (mp.isUsageThresholdSupported()) {
    final MemoryUsage mu = mp.getUsage();
    final long max = mu.getMax();
    final long alert = (max * threshold) / 100;
    mp.setUsageThreshold(alert);

  }
}
```

Where listener is your own implementation of NotificationListener.

Comment: That looks a lot like what I would want. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I use this approach in http://code.google.com/p/pitestrunner/ if you'd like an example. Look the for the MemoryWatchdog class and it's use by MutationTestSlave.

Comment: Don't forget to add a filter when subscribing, i.e.: NotificationFilter filter = x -> MemoryNotificationInfo.MEMORY_THRESHOLD_EXCEEDED.equals(x.getType());
ne.addNotificationListener(tryPreventOom, filter, null);

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
// Get current size of heap in bytes
long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

// Get maximum size of heap in bytes. The heap cannot grow beyond this size.
// Any attempt will result in an OutOfMemoryException.
long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

// Get amount of free memory within the heap in bytes. This size will increase
// after garbage collection and decrease as new objects are created.
long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

As found here - http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/GetHeapSize.html

Comment: I suppose this could make for an okay hack, but I'd rather be notified automatically when a certain threshold is met, rather than having to poll the memory status at a given interval (kinda like the memory notifications on iOS).

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way to get notified automatically based on a given threshold unless you write a poller yourself to do this in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `WeakReferences` for the discardable results, then they will be discarded if necessary for space reasons.

Comment: I can't leave it to the GC's discretion, as I need to review objects before deciding they're deletable.

Comment: +1: Or use SoftReferences which are longer lived, WeakReference are always discarded on a GC.  You can keep a ReferenceQueue to be notified of object which might be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but can't [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) solve your purpose ??