# How to render editable layers

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, layer

I writing a image compositing app where it should be possible to arrange images on different layers. So what I currently do is to merge (draw one bitmap after another) on a canvas. 
The user should be able to remove any of the layers at any time (also undo).

My problem is related to memory management: I fear OutOfMemoryExceptions when keeping every layer as bitmap object in memory. But merging is a problem: As soon as I merge all bitmaps, there is no way to separate them again (obviously).
I was wondering about [saveLayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#saveLayer(android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint,%20int)), it seems you can save and restore data, but I don't really understand whether it could be helpful for me.

I thought about reducing the resolution of the images on the layers, but then the question "which resolution is the right one?" pops up. After all the resolution would depend on the (dynamic) amount of layers and the available system memory.

Anyone has a proposal on how to handle this requirement?

Comment: At a time you deal with only one image so keep in memory only two bitmaps: the current one and the second one which is a merged set of all other bitmaps,  of course you need to rebuild it each time you select other bitmap to use

Answer (score 1):

For the merging problem, what if you instead had multiple canvases, perhaps as part of a custom `ImageView`, which you dynamically add as layers in a `FrameLayout`? The compositing part would then be simply handled by the layout, and you could your make your draggable images appear/disappear without redrawing the unaffected images simply by adding/removing views from `FrameLayout`.

For the memory issue, I can't think of many ideas except to a) set the max res of each layer to something sensible given the devices screen size, b) experiment with using compressed bitmaps like `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` (with a perhaps unacceptable compromise in color fidelity), c) [query the usable heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163228/how-to-dynamically-monitor-java-heap-size) and limit the number of layers accordingly.