# java library for tracking java heap size?

Tags: java, heap-memory

Is there a Java library(.jar) file I can download and use the API to track the heap size for my program? If there isn't one how would I go about creating one?

Comment: This might steer you to the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163228/how-to-dynamically-monitor-java-heap-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Runtime` class:

*Current heap size (it can grow until the allowed maximum is reached):*

```
long hSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

*Maximum heap size:*

```
long hMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

*How much of the current heap size is free:*

```
long hFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean might be useful