# Auto-detect memory in weblogic with email notification when memory goes down

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I am very new to weblogic. Is it possible to auto-detect when the memory of the application that is hosted in weblogic goes down. Is it possible send email notification if the memory available is less than 50%? I am on weblogic 10.3.6.

I mean not by using any profiler tools, is there any feature in weblogic or any script that we can write for weblogic?

no, its not, my question mentions not by using profiling tools like VisualVM, Jconsole etc. does weblogic server has memory monitoring and alerting the admin user when memory is below certain percentage? –

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically monitor Java heap size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163228/how-to-dynamically-monitor-java-heap-size)

Comment: no, its not, my question mentions not by using profiling tools like VisualVM, Jconsole etc. does weblogic server has memory monitoring and alerting the admin user when memory is below certain percentage?

Comment: WLS has a scripting tool called WLST.   Examples - http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=5838

Comment: WebLogic Server provides such a functionality OOB with WLDF (WebLogic Diagnostic Framework) It provides metrics monitoring (heap free current) and actions (sending emails) can be triggered  based on values.
Read this http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=436