# Monitoring and throttling on memory usage on cloud foundry java application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I need to throttle the usage of an app hosted on CloudFoundry.

For that, my Java code has variables storing the following

```
long L1 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
long L2 = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
long L3 = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

However, when i use the command *cf app* on cmd and try to get the value, it is nowhere close to any of the three L1, L2, L3 values. So how can I get the *cf app* command output value in my Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, the JVM (java 8 & 9) is not container aware (this is supposed to happen at some point though, maybe 11?). When you run functions to query the memory usage, it's going to return information pertaining to the whole machine or VM where the app is running.

In Cloud Foundry, you can get the memory limit for your application by looking at the `MEMORY_LIMIT` environment variable. I think using a MemoryMXBean, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2168116/1585136), would be the way to get current usage. You could then subtract current usage from the `MEMORY_LIMIT` and have a approximation of how close you are to the limit.

Just note that there will be a small amount of overhead, as Cloud Foundry runs a couple small processes in your container (pid-0 & ssh mainly). The overhead is pretty small though, I think it was around 25M last I looked.